# How to set the titlecolor of a UIAlertAction in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, ios14, xcode12

I would like to set the text color of my UIAlertAction to red. Does anyone know how to do that? I would be very happy to hear from you. Best regards

[image]

Comment: Search for `UIAlertController` `NSAttributedString`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
cancelAction.setValue(yourColor, forKey: "titleTextColor")
```

where `yourColor` is the `UIColor` you want to set